Parallax Website Animations not working properly
I am trying to build this parallax website and on scrolling down the page the leaf should slowly hide itself to the left side of the screen.
I don't know why it's not working. If anyone can fix this please let me know.
Like the leaf in the picture below it will spawn close to the left side of the screen and then after I start scrolling down it will slowly move farther into the left of the scren until I can't see it anymore.
The leaf.style.marginRight = -value + 'px'; should be working but it's not.


const title = document.querySelector('h2');
const leaf = document.querySelector('.bush');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;
  // console.log(value)
  title.style.marginTop = value * 4.8 + 'px';

  leaf.style.marginRight = -value + 'px';
});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

body,
html {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  --black: rgb(0, 1, 42);
  --lightblue: rgb(55, 127, 243);
  --red: rgb(255, 72, 72);
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(197, 212, 248);
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.navbar .links {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.links p {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--lightblue);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.links p:hover {
  background: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.links .login {
  padding: 10px 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(33, 105, 250);
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links .login:hover {
  background-color: rgb(58, 137, 255);
}

content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bush {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -6;
  width: 200px;
  top: calc(50% + -1000px);
  left: calc(50% + -920px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mountains {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.bush {
  transform: translateZ(-9px) scale(2);
}

.trees {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}

.mountains,
.trees,
.bush {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #454444;
}

section {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/75d7c65c9d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="links">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>About</p>
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Blog</p>
        <button class="login">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <content>
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/vKWYw.png" class="bush">
      <img src="../Images/mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" class="mountains">
      <img src="../Images/trees.png" alt="trees" class="trees" id="trees">
      <h2>Parallax Website</h2>
    </content>
    <section>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque a et, fugit sint officia exercitationem? Aliquid laborum et sed tempore harum, quibusdam aut qui consectetur quisquam eligendi ullam optio culpa illum magni repudiandae, a eaque. Esse sit
      beatae praesentium quam vero, quaerat veritatis, tempora aut quo fugit dicta recusandae consequatur obcaecati quos perferendis nihil nostrum rerum id quidem. Aliquid corporis error sequi similique eos autem delectus cupiditate blanditiis! Praesentium
      voluptate optio blanditiis. Quas illo voluptatum at excepturi reiciendis sit voluptatibus incidunt, enim amet quos. Dolore voluptas nulla eius pariatur dicta fugiat rerum totam, nobis ducimus tenetur illum ad cupiditate quo. Consequatur voluptas
      vel perspiciatis distinctio suscipit ducimus! Natus dicta atque eligendi, totam molestias deserunt animi non esse ex alias dignissimos omnis explicabo unde voluptate corrupti voluptates repellat officia pariatur nobis. Ea ipsum atque blanditiis
      eius officia at pariatur impedit voluptatibus saepe labore non, voluptatem architecto ab quis esse nesciunt nostrum sequi iure? Voluptates, iusto ut! Voluptas provident distinctio debitis tenetur iste, molestias vitae esse quasi dicta, sed necessitatibus,
      corrupti aliquid voluptatum fugit animi nulla. Porro quaerat laborum, vitae aliquid, ipsum quidem, ea laudantium exercitationem corporis quae recusandae eveniet! Doloribus velit deleniti impedit ratione nihil, dicta amet possimus fugit esse illum
      voluptatem tempore eveniet commodi natus. Incidunt voluptatum, porro unde nobis exercitationem veniam, autem nemo repellat saepe animi aperiam facere minima sunt in expedita quae optio eaque nulla atque omnis, perspiciatis placeat consequatur debitis?
      Mollitia et beatae excepturi quos, expedita itaque quasi! Quae, adipisci. Repellat fugiat tempora quibusdam error, sit sint inventore a illum, sapiente eos reprehenderit quis enim! Illo beatae animi, aperiam pariatur officiis neque illum quia error
      ullam, quaerat ex soluta sequi tenetur dolore perspiciatis iusto deserunt saepe nulla quam! Dolorum quisquam vero id omnis quo maiores velit fugit, odit consequatur aspernatur doloribus excepturi sequi odio deleniti, fuga architecto? Lorem, ipsum
      dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel
      quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa
      nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi,
      inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia
      blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium
      fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate
      modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore
      culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis
      iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus
      voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio?
      Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima
      delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam
      labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae
      cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae!
      Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error
      assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto
      nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit.
      Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit
      ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam
      aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis
      nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat,
      ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero
      maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem
      dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam
      a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem
      natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi
      natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi
      praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis
      quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti
      non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus
      asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae
      quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate
      cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas
      quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit
      amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non
      dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum
      hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates
      corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas,
      pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque
      blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda!
      Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis
      error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora
      eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem
      adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste
      recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi
      quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi
      illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium
      quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam
      odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae
      repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis
      soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos
      veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo
      blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis,
      deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam
      a?
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




The scroll event is not being registered in the script through document.addEventListener, because you have set height: 100vh; and overflow-y: auto; to the container and as a result, the container is receiving the event and not the document. You have to remove height: 100vh; from .container to get it to work. I don't know exactly where should the leaf be vertically, so I have set it to my liking. Also, your Javascript is actually moving the leaf to the right instead of the left. You have to use positive value for 'value' in your script.


const title = document.querySelector('h2');
const leaf = document.querySelector('.bush');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;
  // console.log(value)
  title.style.marginTop = value * 4.8 + 'px';

  leaf.style.marginRight = value + 'px';
});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

body,
html {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  --black: rgb(0, 1, 42);
  --lightblue: rgb(55, 127, 243);
  --red: rgb(255, 72, 72);
}

.container {
  //height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(197, 212, 248);
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.navbar .links {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.links p {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--lightblue);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.links p:hover {
  background: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.links .login {
  padding: 10px 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(33, 105, 250);
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links .login:hover {
  background-color: rgb(58, 137, 255);
}

content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bush {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -6;
  width: 200px;
  top: calc(-50% + -1300px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mountains {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.bush {
  transform: translateZ(-9px) scale(2);
}

.trees {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}

.mountains,
.trees,
.bush {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #454444;
}

section {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/75d7c65c9d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="links">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>About</p>
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Blog</p>
        <button class="login">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <content>
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/vKWYw.png" class="bush">
      <img src="../Images/mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" class="mountains">
      <img src="../Images/trees.png" alt="trees" class="trees" id="trees">
      <h2>Parallax Website</h2>
    </content>
    <section>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque a et, fugit sint officia exercitationem? Aliquid laborum et sed tempore harum, quibusdam aut qui consectetur quisquam eligendi ullam optio culpa illum magni repudiandae, a eaque. Esse sit
      beatae praesentium quam vero, quaerat veritatis, tempora aut quo fugit dicta recusandae consequatur obcaecati quos perferendis nihil nostrum rerum id quidem. Aliquid corporis error sequi similique eos autem delectus cupiditate blanditiis! Praesentium
      voluptate optio blanditiis. Quas illo voluptatum at excepturi reiciendis sit voluptatibus incidunt, enim amet quos. Dolore voluptas nulla eius pariatur dicta fugiat rerum totam, nobis ducimus tenetur illum ad cupiditate quo. Consequatur voluptas
      vel perspiciatis distinctio suscipit ducimus! Natus dicta atque eligendi, totam molestias deserunt animi non esse ex alias dignissimos omnis explicabo unde voluptate corrupti voluptates repellat officia pariatur nobis. Ea ipsum atque blanditiis
      eius officia at pariatur impedit voluptatibus saepe labore non, voluptatem architecto ab quis esse nesciunt nostrum sequi iure? Voluptates, iusto ut! Voluptas provident distinctio debitis tenetur iste, molestias vitae esse quasi dicta, sed necessitatibus,
      corrupti aliquid voluptatum fugit animi nulla. Porro quaerat laborum, vitae aliquid, ipsum quidem, ea laudantium exercitationem corporis quae recusandae eveniet! Doloribus velit deleniti impedit ratione nihil, dicta amet possimus fugit esse illum
      voluptatem tempore eveniet commodi natus. Incidunt voluptatum, porro unde nobis exercitationem veniam, autem nemo repellat saepe animi aperiam facere minima sunt in expedita quae optio eaque nulla atque omnis, perspiciatis placeat consequatur debitis?
      Mollitia et beatae excepturi quos, expedita itaque quasi! Quae, adipisci. Repellat fugiat tempora quibusdam error, sit sint inventore a illum, sapiente eos reprehenderit quis enim! Illo beatae animi, aperiam pariatur officiis neque illum quia error
      ullam, quaerat ex soluta sequi tenetur dolore perspiciatis iusto deserunt saepe nulla quam! Dolorum quisquam vero id omnis quo maiores velit fugit, odit consequatur aspernatur doloribus excepturi sequi odio deleniti, fuga architecto? Lorem, ipsum
      dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel
      quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa
      nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi,
      inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia
      blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium
      fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate
      modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore
      culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis
      iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus
      voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio?
      Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima
      delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam
      labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae
      cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae!
      Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error
      assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto
      nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit.
      Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit
      ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam
      aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis
      nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat,
      ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero
      maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem
      dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam
      a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem
      natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi
      natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi
      praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis
      quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti
      non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus
      asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae
      quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate
      cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas
      quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit
      amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non
      dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum
      hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates
      corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi illo architecto quibusdam voluptas,
      pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque
      blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda!
      Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis
      error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora
      eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem
      adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste
      recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis, deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi
      quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam a? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Illo libero sit, voluptates corporis, doloremque temporibus blanditiis quo ipsam nisi ducimus cum totam aut, laborum quibusdam illum iure odio? Eveniet nisi perspiciatis tenetur fuga impedit! Soluta vel quia dolore odit iure deserunt modi
      illo architecto quibusdam voluptas, pariatur autem doloremque ducimus deleniti non aspernatur quos libero perspiciatis nisi laboriosam porro amet. Minima delectus aspernatur totam libero aperiam pariatur ipsa nemo, facilis dolorem, vitae praesentium
      quas fugit laborum laboriosam doloremque blanditiis expedita non. Necessitatibus asperiores laboriosam, laborum fugiat, ipsum minus quae nisi quibusdam labore voluptatem, id maiores ut deleniti quas. Commodi, inventore molestias. Quod quibusdam
      odit aliquid nihil nostrum eveniet sunt assumenda! Perspiciatis odit repudiandae quod sapiente voluptatibus impedit vero maxime sint sequi harum quasi molestiae cum recusandae illum quae modi, praesentium quia blanditiis doloribus voluptatum beatae
      repellendus. Repellendus deserunt veniam perspiciatis error non, nostrum ea cupiditate cumque ullam impedit tempore quidem dignissimos quo quia voluptas molestiae! Molestiae inventore iusto ipsum laudantium fugiat expedita nam consequatur, officiis
      soluta, hic qui, sint temporibus porro sunt tempora eveniet neque unde mollitia voluptas quibusdam veritatis rem laboriosam a? Ea voluptatum optio laboriosam error assumenda pariatur ullam minima voluptate modi laborum dolore, saepe expedita a eos
      veniam! Facilis dolorum ea saepe ipsam, culpa quidem adipisci praesentium eos at velit amet dolorem sit autem ratione, exercitationem natus aut ut cum iste architecto nulla minus rem voluptas aperiam. Tempore culpa, deserunt ex velit harum illo
      blanditiis eos labore consectetur rerum. Autem rem iste recusandae quis consequatur non dolor saepe libero ratione eius, doloremque quasi natus commodi nostrum suscipit. Voluptatem doloribus, error reiciendis iste sapiente, vitae pariatur veritatis,
      deleniti nobis fuga repellendus alias quod eligendi quasi. Autem, necessitatibus. Cum hic, obcaecati accusantium officiis maxime animi praesentium harum reprehenderit ipsam nam perspiciatis ducimus doloribus voluptatum ab illo reiciendis laboriosam
      a?
    </section>
  </div>
</body>



